# handle meta-characters in regular expressions

Tags: c, regex, special-characters

In C, when you escape a character, other than the built-in special characters, it's ASCII code remains unchanged: \+ is the same as +. I'm writing a regular expressions' engine and wonder how one could distinguish \+ and + for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual solution is that the regex engine expects to see `\+`, so if the regex is coming from a string literal, then the programmer will have to write `\\+`. Oddly enough, this approach is even used in some languages that have built-in/standard regex support, so *could* offer special regex syntax.

In theory, an alternative approach is to use a different escape character — say, use `+` for "one or more" and `'+` for "an actual plus sign" — so as not to conflict with that of string literals; but this approach seems to be *infinitely* less popular, for some reason.

Comment: It's amazing how quick I fixed my code using your answer. Thank you so much.